# Java Print formatting decimal

Tags: java

How can I format the following to 4 decimal places. I wasn't able to use `System.out.format("****")` or `System.out.printf("****")`

```
System.out.println("\n Two Distinct Complex Roots Exists: root1 = " +
                    x1 + " + " + imaginary + "i and root2 = " + x2 +" - " +imaginary + "i");
```

here is the quadratic formula that I'm trying to format

```
else if (disc < 0) {
            x1 = x2 = -b / (2 * a);
            imaginary = Math.sqrt(-disc) / (2 * a);
            System.out.format("%.3f%n Two Distinct Complex Roots     Exists: root1 = " +
                    x1 + " + " + imaginary + " and root2 = " + x2 +" - " +imaginary);

        }
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: System.out.printf("\n Two Distinct Complex Roots Exists: root1 = " ,
                        x1 , " + " , imaginary , " and root2 = " , x2 ," - " +imaginary);

System.out.format("%.4f%n Two Distinct Complex Roots Exists: root1 = " +
                        x1 + " + " + imaginary + " and root2 = " + x2 +" - " +imaginary);

Comment: How to use printf: `System.out.printf("text with e.g. %.4f  where numbers should be placed or similar",numbers);`

Comment: I have actually looked through a lot of similar problems and try to use them, but since I have multiple variables it starts giving me errors.

Answer (score 2):

```java
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

Comment: welcome, a vote up will be gd